# Why is LaunchedEffect(true) suspicious?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on implementing MVI using compose.  In order for me to follow the proper event loop, I need to propagate clicks events through my view model and then observe side effects.  I have looked at a few implementations and they all use `LaunchedEffect(true)` to observe side effects and take actions.

I have a similar setup for example:

```
@Composable
fun HelloComposeScreen(
    viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    onClickedNext: () -> Unit
) {
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        viewModel.sideEffect.collectLatest { sideEffect ->
            when (sideEffect) {
                DashboardSideEffect.CreateParty -> onClickedNext()
            }
        }
    }
    Button(
        onClick = { viewModel.onEvent(UserEvent.ClickedButton)},
    ) {
        Text("Click Me")
    }
}
```

This results in me using `LaunchedEffect(true)` for any screen that has navigation or one time events but the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#rememberupdatedstate) has this warning

> Warning: LaunchedEffect(true) is as suspicious as a while(true). Even though there are valid use cases for it, always pause and make sure that's what you need.

My questions are:

- When exactly does the `LaunchedEffect` get canceled? The documentation says that it matches the lifecycle of the call site. Is that the composition in this case?
- Considering that the official documentation has a warning there?  Should I not be using this `LaunchedEffect(true)` setup for observing side effects through my project? What would be an alternative?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one. It'll be hard for others to find the needed answer. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I've answered your question about `LaunchedEffect`, and the part about MVI is out of scope in this question, you can create an other one.

Comment: I put the questions together since they are related to each other.  I can remove the last one about the MVI but the second one might be considered opinionated if I ask it on its own.

Comment: Google uses `LaunchedEffect(Unit) {` inside `produceState` so this warning can easily be disregarded entirely, albeit you should always ensure that you actually do not need any keys by which the coroutine would cancel and restart.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `LaunchedEffect` is canceled along with its coroutine in two variants:

1. The passed `key` argument(s) is changed - in this case the current `LaunchedEffect` will be cancelled and a new one will be created.
2. `LaunchedEffect` is removed from the life tree, for example, in case you put it (or its parent at any level) in an `if` block and the condition becomes `false`.

If you do not need to pass any `key` that should restart `LaunchedEffect`, you can pass `Unit`. Any other constant, like `true` in your case, is considered suspect because it cannot be changed at runtime and yet may look like complex logic to any coder.

Comment: For your second bullet "LaunchedEffect is removed from the life tree..".  You said that is removed from the composition when wrapped in a conditional but in my case it isn't wrapped in a conditional.  So when exactly will it get removed?  Is it when `HelloComposeScreen` leaves composition?

Comment: @Naveed yes, whenever your composable leaves composition. Whether it's by conditional or navigation or anything else

Comment: LaunchedEffect(true) and LaunchedEffect(Unit) have equivalent behaviour.

Android documentation:

To create an effect that matches the lifecycle of the call site, a never-changing constant like Unit or true is passed as a parameter.

Comment: @DissidentDev yes, just like that you can use `false` or any other constant, but to a person reading your code it may look like some kind of logic, so it is safer to use `Unit`. That's why my answer about.

Comment: If I had read the documentation saying Unit and True are ok, I wouldn't be that person feeling anything suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

The `LacunchedEffect` is a `Composable` function and it runs coroutines in a `coroutineScope`.

The `coroutineScope` will be canceled and restarted in two cases:

1. When the passed `keys` to `LaunchedEffect` gets changed. Changing a passed key from value `x` to `y` cancels the current `coroutineScope`, and then launching the block of code inside `LaunchedEffect` again with a new passed `keys`.
2. When the `LaucnhedEffect` exits the composition. That means in a later composition if the `LaucnhedEffect` does not recompose. For example, because it's inside an `if` statement that gets evaluated as `false` or if one of the parent composables in the composition tree exits the composition.

Example:

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun MyComposable(authorId: Int, showReadMore: Boolean) {
    // ... logic....
    
    // When showReadMore is false, the latest LaunchedEffect composable exits the composition (the coroutineScope will be cancelled)
    if (showReadMore) {
        // Changing the value of authorId when showReadMore is true, cancels the coroutineScope and launch the block again.
        LaunchedEffect(authorId) {
            // Get more info of the author using suspend function
            // Since we use LaunchedEffect to run suspend function(s) inside
        }
    }
}
```

For the second question: Passing any value like `false`, `true`, `1`, `2`, and `Unit` gives the same result. Passing `Unit` makes the code more sense and easier to read because it indicates `void` which means that we don't care about restarting the `coroutineScope` in the first case (when `keys` changes) because the keys are `void`.