# Append to LazyList from a flow in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to read a file line by line and each line is a new item in a LazyList. I have a flow that I would subscribe to, to listen for each new line

```
class LogcatService(private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) {
    private var _mutableLogcatListener: MutableSharedFlow<String> = MutableSharedFlow(0, 1, BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)
    val logcatListener: SharedFlow<String> = _mutableLogcatListener

    private var _logcatJob: Job? = null

    fun startLogcat(){
        _logcatJob = coroutineScope.launch {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c")
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat")
                .inputStream
                .bufferedReader()
                .useLines { lines ->
                    lines.forEach { newLine ->
                        _mutableLogcatListener.tryEmit(newLine)
                    }
                }
        }

    }

    fun stopLogcat(){
        _logcatJob?.cancel()
    }
}
```

Then in the activity I would listen to the flow to append each line that was read

```
@Composable
fun LogcatList(logcatService: LogcatService){
    val value = logcatService.logcatListener.collectAsState(initial = "")
    val content by remember { mutableStateOf(mutableListOf<String>())}
    content.add(value.value)
    LazyColumn {
        items(content) { message ->
            Text(text = message,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

It however I dont seem to get any flow updates in the composable.

I am pretty new to jetpack compose so I dont know what I am doing wrong. Using regular xml android I would just append the item to recyclerview and that would be that but I am trying to learn compose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```kotlin
val content by remember { mutableStateOf(mutableListOf<String>()) }
```

Should give you the following warning:

> Creating a MutableState object with a mutable collection type

Mutable state is a value holder. It can only trigger recomposition when the value itself changes. But it cannot track when the value state is changes - that's what you're doing when mutating a mutable list.

Instead you can use `mutableStateListOf`:

```kotlin
val content = remember { mutableStateListOf<String>() }
```

After this change the text should appear, ofc if you don't forget to run `startLogcat`.

An other problem in your code is with this line:

```kotlin
content.add(value.value)
```

In Compose recomposition can happen often, up to once for each frame in case of animations. It shouldn't gonna cause problems with your code, as you only have a single state changing, but generally it's a bad practice to mutate state directly from `@Composable`, check out read more in side effects [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) and [thinking in compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#recomposition).

The correct way of updating `content` in your case can look like this:

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    logcatService.logcatListener
        .collect(content::add)
}
```

An other solution is not using `Flow` in the first place, and move `mutableStateListOf` directly into your `LogcatService`.

Comment: What's the significance of that parameter in `LaunchedEffect`?

Comment: @YaMiN it's a required parameter, not sure what your answer is, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70439062/3585796) will help?