# Android Compose - How to handle ViewModel clear focus event in JetPackCompose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

How to handle ViewModel clear focus event in JetPackCompose?

I have a coroutines channel that sometimes notify my screen to clear the `TextField` focus

How is the best way to notify my composable to clear focus?

I tried to create a mutableStateFlow, but is there a better way to do it?

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val clearFocus by viewModel.clearFocus.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    AppTheme {
            HomeScreenContent(
                clearFocus
            )
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    val clearFocus = MutableStateFlow(false)

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(3000)
            clearFocus.value = true
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreenContent(
    clearFocus: Boolean
) {
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    var value by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("initial value") }
    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = {
            value = it
        }
    )
    if(clearFocus) {
        focusManager.clearFocus()
    }
}
```

When a coroutine channel notifies the `ViewModel`, I want to clear the `TextField` focus, how is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of delegating to the `HomeScreenContent` the duty of clearing the focus you could do it in `HomeScreen`.

You should not use a stateFlow if you want to do an action that does not affect the compose tree. Instead of using StateFlow use a SharedFlow when you want to trigger an Event.

#### Using a SharedFlow

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    val clearFocusEvent = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(3000)
            clearFocusEvent.emit(Unit)
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

   
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.clearFocusEvent.collectLatest {
            focusManager.clearFocus()
        }
    }

    AppTheme {
            HomeScreenContent()
    }
}
```

#### Using a sealed interface as event

If you want to have more events between your VM and Composable or just a cleaner code, you can make a sealed interface that will represent the events

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    val homeScreenEvent = MutableSharedFlow<HomeScreenEvent>()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(3000)
            homeScreenEvent.emit(HomeScreenEvent.ClearFocus)
        }
    }
}

sealed interface HomeScreenEvent {
    object ClearFocus: HomeScreenEvent
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.homeScreenEvent.collectLatest {
            when(it) {
                HomeScreenEvent.ClearFocus ->  focusManager.clearFocus()
            }
        }
    }

    AppTheme {
        HomeScreenContent()
    }
}
```

Now when you'll add an event you just have to handle the new case in the `when`

Comment: awesome, thanks for the response. Btw LaunchedEffect(Unit) looks a little be strange at first, but I checked here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433092/why-is-launchedeffecttrue-suspicious, it looks fine